# Pygames import image from file Error:"couldn't open

Tags: python

hi guys im having problem in importing an image to my pygames script.

my code:

```
from gasp import*

begin_graphics(800,600,"My Game",color.GREEN)

Image("C:\Users\Yuvinng\Downloads\982960f3d1joong.jpg",(400,300), None, None)

end_graphics()
```

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\testing idle codes\GASP", line 5, in <module>
    Image("C:\Users\Yuvinng\Downloads\982960f3d1joong.jpg",(400,300), None, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gasp\api.py", line 267, in __init__
    backend.create_image(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gasp\backend.py", line 302, in create_image
    obj.sprite.image = pygame.image.load(obj.path_name).convert()
error: Couldn't open C:\Users\Yuvinng\Downloads\982960f3d1joong.jpg
```

can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Does the file exist in the first place at the designated location? The error message says it cannot find it there. One of the good practices is to use `raw string` by prefixing the path with an `r` to prevent inadvertent escapes.

```
Image(r"C:\Users\Yuvinng\Downloads\982960f3d1joong.jpg",(400,300), None, None)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\testing idle codes\GASP", line 5, in <module>
    Image(r"C:\Users\Yuvinng\Downloads\982960f3d1joong.jpg",(400,300), None, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gasp\api.py", line 267, in __init__
    backend.create_image(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gasp\backend.py", line 302, in create_image
    obj.sprite.image = pygame.image.load(obj.path_name).convert()
error: Couldn't open C:\Users\Yuvinng\Downloads\982960f3d1joong.jpg

Comment: the file does exist. if it doesnt exist it would say "could'nt find"